# add days with date , different timezone not working

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I want to add number of days with an existing date fetch from the database.When the timezone is (UTC+ 8:OO)Pacific Time US&CANADA momentjs addition working perfectly,But when i change timezone to (UTC+ 5:3O)Chennai,Kolkatta Momentjs addition not working,It returns the date that we given to add.

```
var inputtilldate =moment($scope.lasttilldate).add($scope.remdays-0, 'days');
```

This is the code for addition

Answer (score 0):

Add format to the moment()

```
var inputtilldate =moment($scope.lasttilldate).add($scope.remdays-0, 'days').format();
```